# consume SOAP web service with WS-Security

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, digital-signature, ws-security

I'm trying to consume a web service which uses WS Security (usernametoken, signature and encryption). I don't have any information on the web service except the wsdl.

With wsdl.exe, I have created my proxy class and I'm also able to call a web service method. It shows errors

> "No signature in message! (from client)"

How can I add the signature and encryption to the SOAP web service call?

Comment: you might want to post the app.config and web.config, and any other code that you have tried. Also have you tried using a 3rd party web service caller like soapUI?

Answer (score 1):

You should use WCF. Why? ASMX web services are old technology and doesn't support WS-Security. To add WS-Security to ASMX you must either do it manually (a lot of very complex specifications to implement) or use WSE. Both ASMX and WSE are replaced by WCF since .NET 3.0 so unless you have to use .NET 2.0 your choice should be WCF.

First of all try to use svcutil.exe or Add service reference in Visual Studio and if it doesn't create proxy for you post security part of WSDL to your question. We can try to help you with configuration.

Comment: hi, do you mean, i should use an wcf client for consuming the webservice? i will try to use svcutil.exe ...

Comment: Yes WCF is only newer technology to create or consume services.

Comment: i have tried the svcutil.exe, unfortunately i get an error 

"Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.Se
rviceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Schema with target namespace '<url>' coul
d not be found.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='<url>']/wsdl:portType[@name='<name>']" 

i think the error occurs if the namespace url is not reachable!? with wsdl.exe i don't had any errors. 
is there an another way to create the wcf client?

Comment: Namespace is just identifier, it doesn't have to be real url. Are you sure that WSDL doesn't contain any includes or external XSDs?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for the hint with the xsd, that was the problem for generating proxy und config with svcutils! i have merged the config and implement the proxy file. what’s next? do have an link for an tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use WS-Security, you need WCF.

WSE was the interim "add-on" package from Microsoft that supported WS-Security on the first version web services stack - the one that used WSDL.exe. It's my understanding that WSE is no longer supported.